# How can I cross compile ctest?

Tags: cmake, arm, cross-compiling, ctest

I want to use ctest on arm target system.
So tried to arm-crosscompile cmake(which includes ctest) but only failed.
I built arm cross compiler with cross-ng as guided in the url below:

http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/426

My test arm machine is raspberry-pi. So the guide above helped me get arm cross compiler.

With this arm cross compiler I successfully built and tested helloworld!

But, with this arm cross compiler I fail to compile cmake-2.8.12.2 as shown below.

> mkdir -p /somepath/bin/cmake
>
> cd /somepath/bin/cmake
>
> cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/me/bin/RaspberryPi/CMakeToolChain/Toolchain-RaspberryPi.cmake /somepath/src/cmake-2.8.12.2

With this way, I get errors but cmake, ctest and cpack are built. And they are arm binaries.
But when I scp ctest into my Raspberry-Pi and test, it fails with the message below:

> ./ctest: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not
>   found (required by ./ctest)

Let me post my toolchain file.

> SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
>
> SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
>
> SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER
>   /home/me/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
>
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
>   /home/me/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++)
>
> SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
>   /home/me/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi)
>
> SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
>   SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
>   SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

Could someone guide me how to get arm version of ctest?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the error message below:

> ./ctest: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not
>   found (required by ./ctest)

My target machine is raspberry-pi. And the version of libc.so.6 on it is version 2.13!
I had to configure this from the menuconfig of crosstool-ng.
Choosing the right version of libc from the menuconfig of crosstool-ng is the solution.

Thank you very much stackoverflows.com!